# Getting Error for changing in .xproj file while migrating to asp.net core rc2

Tags: .net-core-rc2, dnvm, migrating

While migrating to ASP.Net RC 2, I am getting this error "The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.". When I make  changes in xproj file. I have VS 2015 Update 2 and .Net Core from here https://www.microsoft.com/net/download on my machine.

Also for uninstalling dnvm, it asked for VersionOrAlias.

Comment: Did you install the SDK? If you did, have you tried also installing .NET Core Tooling Preview 1 for Visual Studio 2015 (it's on the same page you linked to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved. I installed ".NET Core SDK Installer
(Preview 1)" from above link "https://www.microsoft.com/net/download" in my question and it installed all the required components for RC2.